# 2nd order nonhomogenous ODE with delta function (Green's Fn)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta, greens-function

I am trying to solve $\frac{u'}{(1+x^2)^2}-\frac{u''}{1+x^2}=\delta(x-\alpha), u(0)=u(1)=0$

Wolfram alpha gives $u(x)=-1/3(x^3+3x)(\sigma(x)-1)$

I have no idea how to set up an ansatz. Maybe some property of green's function would help.

Many thanks.

Comment: Note that the left hand side can be written as the derivative of $-\frac{u'}{1+x^2}.$

Comment: @md2perpe Thanks! I figured it out!